# JavaScript error using date picker inside an update panel?

Tags: development, javascript

I placed the SharePoint date picker control inside an update panel and when I click on the calendar it gives me this error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property
>   'clickDatePicker' is null or undefined, not a Function object

The control works outside the update panel without any issues. How do I make it work inside the panel?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.SE! You have a great question here, but I made some slight improvements based on [our  guidelines](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115/have-any-tips-for-editing-questions/116#116). You can also read [How to Ask](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more general guidelines.

Answer (score 6):

Just include the datepicker.js file explicitly on the page

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/datepicker.js"></script>
```